# dispatch_async with xml parser Not Working

Tags: ios, xml, uitableview, dispatch-async

i am using dispatch_async when parsing xml data in a uitable view here is my code:

```
- (void) Parse{
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
     NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://messages.xml"];
     NSData *xmlData=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post]];
     xmlParserObject =[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];
     [xmlParserObject setDelegate:self];
     dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [xmlParserObject parse];
     });
     });
    [messageList reloadData];
}
```

now uitableview not showing any data in it. it was working perfectly before dispatch_async

Comment: You call to `[messageList reloadData]` doesn't happen after the data is fetched, it happens immediately after the first dispatch. Remember, when you dispatch, code execution on the main thread continues immediately with the next statement, which is `reloadData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have problem in your code. Please reload table data in `dispatch_get_main_queue()`

```
- (void) Parse {
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://messages.xml"];
        NSData *xmlData=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post]];
        xmlParserObject =[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];
        [xmlParserObject setDelegate:self];
        [xmlParserObject parse];
        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [messageList reloadData];
        });
    });    
}
```

Comment: Why do the xml parsing on the main thread? I would move the line `[xmlParserObject parse];` above the call to `dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue()' so that it runs in the background. Only the call to reloadData needs to be done on the main thread.

Comment: puts only reload code in to dispatch_get_main_queue() and other code where you want doesn't issue

Comment: "puts only reload code in to dispatch_get_main_queue() and other code where you want doesn't issue". Huh? That isn't a sentence. Putting the XML parsing code in the main thread will cause the UI to freeze while the XML is being parsed. If the XML is large, it could cause a very long UI Freeze, and could even cause the system to kill your app as unresponsive. It **does** matter.